# Comparing different type of Objects with comparable

Tags: java, list, collections, comparable

`A.java`

```
public class A implements Comparable {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public A(String a, String b) {
        id = a;
        name = b;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        A a = (A) o;
        return id.compareTo(a.getId());
    }
}
```

`B.java`

```
public class B implements Comparable {
    private String b_id;
    private String other;

    public B(String a, String b) {
        b_id = a;
        other = b;
    }

    public String getBId() {
        return b_id;
    }

    public void setBId(String id) {
        this.b_id = id;
    }

    public String getOther() {
        return other;
    }

    public void setOther(String other) {
        this.other = other;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        B b = (B) o;
        return b_id.compareTo(b.getId());
    }
}
```

`Learn.java`

```
public class Learn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
        List<Object> listAll = new ArrayList<Object>();
        listA.add(new A("aa", "bb"));
        listA.add(new A("ae", "bbn"));
        listA.add(new A("dfr", "GSDS"));
        listB.add(new B("nm", "re"));
        listB.add(new B("asd", "asfa"));

        listAll.addAll(listA);
        listAll.addAll(listB);
        Collections.sort(listAll);
        for (Object o : listAll) {
            if (o instanceof A)
                System.out.println(o.getId);
            else if (o instanceof B)
                Syatem.out.println(o.getBId);
        }

    }

}
```

The error i get is at the line `Collections.sort(listAll);`
It says.

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable
for the arguments (List<Object>). The inferred type Object is not a valid substitute
for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

What to do? Also is the rest of the logic all right?

What i am trying to do is have a list of A and list of B with one attribute same as id; though the variable name is not the same. i.e `id` in `A` and `bid` in B.
Now i put both the lists in ListAll and do sort on them on the same variable id/bid. 
I have A and B implementing Comparable.

and my listAll is of type Object?

how do I do it?
thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is at that line?

Comment: `listAll` must be defined as being a `List` of `Comparable` objects if you want the sort to work. If you want to be able to store both `A` and `B` instances in the list and sort them, you must define a `Comparable` superclass from which they can both subclass. This superclass must be capable of sorting any combination of `A` and `B` instances.

Comment: In additino to making a `List` of `Comparable`, shouldn't a classes `compareTo` method take that Object as a parameter? i.e. `A.compareTo(A)`, not `A.compareTo(Object)`?

Comment: @BrianJ No, the general contract of `compareTo` mandates that you accept an `Object`. Typically the first thing you would do is compare for type equality with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a common base class and implement comparison there, as in:

```
abstract class AandBComparable implements Comparable {

  public int compareTo(Object o) {
    AandBComparable ab = (AandBComparable) o;
    return getId().compareTo(ab.getId());
  }

  public abstract String getId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to sort a list, its elements must be comparable to each other. That's not the case here. Instances of A can only be compared with other instances of A. Same for B.

If you want to sort a list containg A and B instances, you need to provide `Comparator` which will happily take two `A`s, two `B`s or an `A` and a `B`, and compare these objects as you want them compared.

```
public class AOrBComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String o1Id = getId(o1);
        String o2Id = getId(o2);
        return o1Id.compareTo(o2Id);
    }

    private String getId(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof A) {
            return ((A) o).getId();
        }
        else if (o instanceof B) {
            return ((B) o).getId();
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only get ID from A or B");
        }
    }
}
```

But maybe A and B should implement the same Identifiable interface, and the list should be a `List<Identifiable>`. This way, you could easily write a comparator that compares two instances of Identifiable, and it would work whether the actual instance is A, B, or any other Identifiable.

Comment: Which edits? Anyway, my answer still applies to your question as it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the exception raises where you tell, but rather in a call to `sort()`

Anyway, it means something like

"The sort method expects a `List` of elements that implement comparable. But you tell him that you are giving a list of `Object`, and **not all Object implement Comparable**. So, the compiler cannot be sure that at realtime the objects passed in the list will implement Comparable (as required), and throws an error"

The solution? Define the list with a bound class that implements Comparable

```
 List<A> listAll = new ArrayList<A>();
```

Update: To have all items in the same list then either:

a) Have all items derive from a common class / interface that implements `Comparable`. Usually this would be the most Object Oriented Programming friendly approach, since if you want to compare both classes they must be somehow related. Either extend B from A, A from B, A and B from another class, or make A and B implement another interface (which itself implements Comparable).

b) As JBNizet said, use a `Comparator`.

Again, I strongly recommend using the a solution.

Comment: but i dont want the final list to be of type A only, i want it to be a kind of collection of both A and B types, that is why i took listAll to be of type Object.

Answer (score 0):

You need a base (dummy) class which will implement `Comparable` and let A and B derive from class. Something like:

```
public abstract class MyComparableClass implements Comparable {
}

public class A extends MyComparableClass {
... // implementation of compareTo
}

public class B extends MyComparableClass {
...// implementation of compareTo
}
```

In your main program then simply define the Collection to be:

```
List<MyComparableClass> listAll = new ArrayList<MyComparableClass>();
```